# How can I populate a table with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I populate a table with JavaScript in the proper way?

```js
function loadTableData() {

  //0: Date
  //1: Name

  var row = document.getElementById("test");

  var x = row.insertCell(0);
  x.innerHTML = "10/17/2018";

  var x = row.insertCell(1);
  x.innerHTML = "john doe";

}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table table-borderless table-striped table-earning">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>file name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="test"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>loadTableData();</script>
```

My current code populates the first two cells but I would like to move to the next column and populate another two cells. Im not sure how to do this the correct way.

Current output
[image]

Comment: You need to append a new row, then populate it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The trick is to loop over your data and use `insertRow` to create a row before you insert the data. You can see that the `tbody` element is empty in this example and each `tr` element is created dynamically.

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table table-borderless table-striped table-earning">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>file name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="testBody"></tbody>
</table>
<script>
  const items1 = [
    { date: "10/17/2018", name: "john doe" },
    { date: "10/18/2018", name: "jane doe" },
  ];
  const items2 = [
    { date: "10/17/2019", name: "john doe" },
    { date: "10/18/2019", name: "jane doe" },
  ];
  function loadTableData(items) {
    const table = document.getElementById("testBody");
    items.forEach( item => {
      let row = table.insertRow();
      let date = row.insertCell(0);
      date.innerHTML = item.date;
      let name = row.insertCell(1);
      name.innerHTML = item.name;
    });
  }
  loadTableData(items1);
  loadTableData(items2);
  loadTableData([]);
</script>
```

Comment: What if i dont want the items to be constant? What if im loading them on the fly and based on a user they could have none or more than two?

Comment: How can i assign the items without being constant. Say i have a loop of strings and im assigning the items through that.

Comment: All you need to do is pass `items` as an argument to the function. I've adjusted it to reflect this. It also works with an empty array. You could change the code to work with just strings instead of objects, but I think your code will be easier to work with if you stick with objects instead for this application.

Comment: or append an array of items somehow.

Answer (score 3):

As the other responder mentioned, you need to work with the document using the DOM. Treat everything as the elements they are in HTML.

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

var rowNode = document.createElement("tr");
var cellNode = document.createElement("td");
var textNode = document.createTextNode("John Doe");

cellNode.appendChild(textNode);
rowNode.appendChild(cellNode);
table.appendChild(rowNode);
```

For further interactions with a table DOM element, the W3C spec ([DOM Interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20121025/table.html#table-interface)) is a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    const courses = [{
    "Name": "Communications",
    "Date": "22 April 2022",
    "Code": "CS368"                
    },
    {
    "Name": "Programming",
    "Date": "22 April 2021",
    "Code": "CS368"                
    },
    {
    "Name": "Networks",
    "Date": "22 April 2002",
    "Code": "CS368"                
    }]
const table = document.getElementById("tableBody");
courses.map(course=>{
   let row = table.insertRow();
   let name = row.insertCell(0);
   name.innerHTML = course.Name;
   let date = row.insertCell(1);
   date.innerHTML = course.Date;
   let code = row.insertCell(2);
   code.innerHTML = course.Code;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Code</th>                                              
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="tableBody">
           
         </tbody>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an HTML expert, but:

I think you have to use *element*.appendChild() to append the child you have created. You shouldn't use the innerHTML, rather use the methods built into the Document Object Model.