# How to format records in an HTML JavaScript page

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

I need help in arranging the output. It’s being displayed side by side, but I want it in tabular form as shown below.
How can I do this?

I am not a developer, but I have to build this app for my project, so bear with my ignorance, please. I am willing to learn.

The part of code generating this data is as follows:

```javascript
get(child(dbref, "Sensor"))
.then((snapshot)=>{
    snapshot.forEach((child)=>{
    let table = document.querySelector('table');
    let template = `
        <tr>
           <td>${child.val().StartTime}</td>
           <td>${child.val().Duration}</td>
           <td>${child.val().GalsPumped}</td>
           <td>${child.val().Cycle}</td>
        </tr>`;
        table.innerHTML += template;
        id_PumpID.innerHTML += "Pump ID: " + child.val().PumpID
        id_StartTime.innerHTML += "StartTime: " + child.val().StartTime;
        id_Cycle.innerHTML += "Cycle: " + child.val().Cycle;
        id_Duration.innerHTML += "Duration: " +  child.val().Duration;
        id_GalsPumped.innerHTML +="GalsPumped: " + child.val().GalsPumped;
     })
    });
```

#### Table structure

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height: 72px;" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height: 18px;">
            <td style="width: 14.5616%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 47.9645%; height: 18px;"><strong>START-TIME</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 19.1545%; height: 18px;"><strong>DURATION-HRS</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 18.3194%; height: 18px;"><strong>GALS-PUMPED</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 18.3194%; height: 18px;"><strong>CYCLE</strong></td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 18px;">
            <td style="width: 14.5616%; height: 18px;"><span style="color: #0000ff;"><strong>PUMP1</strong></span></td>
            <td style="width: 47.9645%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 19.1545%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 18.3194%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 18.3194%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 18px;">
            <td style="width: 14.5616%; height: 18px;"><span style="color: #00ff00;"><strong>PUMP2</strong></span></td>
            <td style="width: 47.9645%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 19.1545%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 18.3194%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 18.3194%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 18px;">
            <td style="width: 14.5616%; height: 18px;"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>PUMP3</strong></span></td>
            <td style="width: 47.9645%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 19.1545%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 18.3194%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 18.3194%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

The page is currently looking like this

```
Cycle: 218Cycle: 10
Duration: 0.01222Duration: 0.99278
GalsPumped: 73.33333GalsPumped: 5956.6665
Pump ID: 1Pump ID: 2
StartTime: 10:09:2022 13:13:31StartTime: 10:09:2022 15:43:17
```

I want the following format to be displayed:

```
Pump   StartTime             Cycle   GalsPumped   Duration

1      10:09:2022 13:13:31   218     73.33333     0.01

2      10:09:2022 15:43:17    10     5956.665     0.99278
```

Comment: Create an [HTML table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics), give it a shot, and if you get stuck you can update this question.

Comment: creating a table in html is not a big deal and I can do it , my issue is populating the HTML table with the data generated by forEach loop in conjuction with innerHTML +=

Comment: Definitely use a table for this.
[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52919972/how-can-i-populate-a-table-with-javascript)

Comment: in this example all constants are used so its straight forward ,inserting them into the table cell , can you please provide and example where a dynamic variable is being used to populate  the cell using innerHTML?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I populate a table with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52919972/how-can-i-populate-a-table-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first print the column names and then the values against these columns. The column name shouldn't be inside the *foreach* loop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).